# How do I not type the full path to gcc and the MacOSX sdk in terminal?

Tags: c, macos, unix, gcc, terminal

In terminal every time I want to compile a C file I have to type out the full path to both the gcc alias and the MacOSX SDK. For example, to run a main.c fine I would type

```
$ cd /Users/Will/Desktop/C 
$ /Users/Will/Desktop/C/gcc -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk main.c
```

However, my directory is in the Desktop/C folder so I should not have to type the full path, yet when I type

```
$ cd /Users/Will/Desktop/C
$ gcc main.c
```

I get

```
-bash: gcc: command not found
```

Furthermore, it seems that it should already know to look in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk for header files such as stdio.h, yet when I type

```
$ /Users/Will/Desktop/C/gcc main.c
```

I get something like

```
main.c:1:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in your current working directory, use `./gcc`.

Otherwise, point your `$PATH` to that directory, and you'll be able to use it from anywhere as `gcc`.

As for not having to type out the SDK path each time, you could write a simple bash script and place it in your `$HOME/bin` (assuming you've already added `gcc` to your `$PATH`, otherwise add the full path)...

```
#!/bin/sh
gcc -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk "$@"
```

Make sure to give it execute permissions with `chmod +x gcc_wrapper`. Then you should be able to use it from anywhere, and any arguments passed to it wil be tacked on the end.

Comment: @WilliamOliver You could write a bash script that fills in all that for you, and you just pass it the C source file.

Answer (score 0):

in unix systems

open the file `.bashrc` in your home folder

add an alias in that file

eg :

```
alias mygcc="/Users/Will/Desktop/C/gcc"
```

close the terminal and reopen it, now onwards u can use mygcc filename.c for compiling

likewise you can add an alias to mac sdk too .

[Refer this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-aliases-mac-centos-linux-unix.html)